# Remove Rows based on a column value SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a result set for a query that can return results that look like this:

```
VISIT ID | MRN | ORDER NUMBER | ORDER STATUS | STATUS DATETIME
12345678 | 123 | 987654321    | ACITVE       | 2013-06-01 11:00:01.000
12345678 | 123 | 987654321    | DISCONTINUE  | 2013-06-01 11:05:00.000
12345678 | 123 | 987654320    | ACTIVE       | 2013-06-01 11:10:00.000
12345678 | 123 | 987654320    | IN PROGRESS  | 2013-06-01 11:15:00.000
12345678 | 123 | 987654320    | COMPLETE     | 2013-06-01 11:25:00.000
```

What I want to do is get rid of all order numbers that have an order status as Discontinue and obtain the following output:

```
VISIT ID | MRN | ORDER NUMBER | ORDER STATUS | STATUS DATETIME
12345678 | 123 | 987654320    | ACTIVE       | 2013-06-01 11:10:00.000
12345678 | 123 | 987654320    | IN PROGRESS  | 2013-06-01 11:15:00.000
12345678 | 123 | 987654320    | COMPLETE     | 2013-06-01 11:25:00.000
```

The only ways I can think of doing it seem to be overly complicated.  Here is my code so far:

```
DECLARE @SD DATETIME
DECLARE @ED DATETIME
SET @SD = '2013-06-01';
SET @ED = '2013-06-30';

-- COLUMN SELECTION
SELECT PV.PtNo_Num AS 'VISIT ID'
, PV.Med_Rec_No AS 'MRN'
, PV.Adm_Date AS 'ADMIT'
, PV.Dsch_Date AS 'DISC'
, PV.Days_Stay AS 'LOS'
, PV.pt_type AS 'PT TYPE'
, PV.hosp_svc AS 'HOSP SVC'
, SO.ord_no AS 'ORDER NUMBER'
, SO.ent_dtime AS 'ORDER ENTRY TIME'
, SO.svc_desc AS 'ORDER DESCRIPTION'
, OSM.ord_sts AS 'ORDER STATUS'
, SOS.prcs_dtime AS 'ORDER STATUS TIME'

-- DB(S) USED
FROM smsdss.BMH_PLM_PtAcct_V PV
JOIN smsmir.sr_ord SO
ON PV.PtNo_Num = SO.episode_no
JOIN smsmir.sr_ord_sts_hist SOS
ON SO.ord_no = SOS.ord_no
JOIN smsmir.ord_sts_modf_mstr OSM
ON SOS.hist_sts = OSM.ord_sts_modf_cd

-- FILTER(S)
WHERE Adm_Date BETWEEN @SD AND @ED
--AND OSM.ord_sts IN (  <--COMMENTED OUT
--'ACTIVE',             <--COMMENTED OUT
--'IN PROGRESS',        <--COMMENTED OUT
--'COMPLETE'            <--COMMENTED OUT
--)                     <--COMMENTED OUT
AND pv.drg_no IN (067,068,069)
AND SO.svc_cd IN (SVC CODES LIST)
ORDER BY PV.PtNo_Num, SO.ord_no, SOS.prcs_dtime
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thank you,

Comment: whether you're doing a select, delete, or update why can you not just WHERE OrderStatus <> 'DISCONTINUE' ?

Comment: Hi @Volvox when I did that, the `ORDER NUMBER` where it was still in the `ACTIVE` still came up. If at any point the `ORDER NUMBER` hits a status of `DISCONTINUE` I don't want to show any of it's history. The reason being is that I am joining a table that keeps a history of an order so each order number is unique to a patient and so is its status

Comment: Ahh, I think I see what you're getting at. WHERE OrderNumber NOT IN (SELECT OrderNumber FROM x WHERE OrderStatus = 'Discontinue')

Comment: Yeah exactly, I like that let me see if it works right.

Comment: @Volvox that worked, but it addede 47 seconds to the query, think there might be a faster solution? Also you can put that in as the answer so I can mark it answered. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create a list of the Ordernumbers then remove those from the result set using a where clause similar to:

```
WHERE OrderNumber NOT IN
(
   SELECT OrderNumber From smsmir.ord_sts_modf_mstr
   WHERE OrderStatus = 'Discontinue'
)
```

To speed things up, you could first apply any constraints to the main query on the subquery - depending on your result set size and performance expectations it might even be worthwhile to join and filter in the subquery to eliminate a huge set of OrderNumbers if they are not needed. Also, a `DISTINCT` statement might be useful. While it will have to sort and filter, it might be more efficient than a bloated `NOT IN` statement.
You might be able to invert the statement too... I'm assuming you have fewer Discontinued than active, but this may not be the case. An `IN` statement with an OrderStatus <> 'Discontinue' may be faster. If there's a non string indication of the discontinued status that would be preferable to check than a string value.